# How do I force to use ssl with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I want to force my visitors to use https version of my site.
Now, it is redirect to https version if I use the site without the "www" tag,
but if I type "www.example.xyz" it is not redirect to the https version.

Here is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: How many examples for this are there alone here on StackOverflow? 5583649264936?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with another condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTPS}  !^on$
RewriteRule   ^         https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```